# constructor not working with parameter

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
<?php
class Person {
    public $name;
    public $surname;
    public function __construct($name,$surname) {
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->surname=$surname;
    }
}


$person = new Person();
$person->name='Christian';
$person->surname='Sciberras';
?>
```

I don't know why the code is not running instead it shows:

> (Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function Person::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\index.php on line 15 and exactly 2 expected in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\index.php(15): Person->__construct() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\index.php on line 8

Comment: You've made the constructor arguments mandatory, so you have to pass those arguments when you instantiate the object

Comment: Either pass parameters or make them optional with default values.
You can read more about this stuff here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 3):

You have pass like below

```
$person = new Person('Christian','Sciberras');
```

Because you got

```
public function __construct($name,$surname){
                           /*
                              ^      ^  
                              |      |
                            arg1     arg2

                          */
}
```

So it expects you to pass 2 arguments, thats why you got below message

> Too few arguments to function Person::__construct(),

Comment: what do you mean by separate way

Comment: i have already try what u suggest me.  separate way mean  $person->name='Christian';
$person->surname='Sciberras';

Comment: since you made constructor arguments mandatory, you have to pass arguments, when you call class, atleast if you make `public function __construct($name=null,$surname=null) { `, it will work, both way